# Docker build error OCI runtime create failed "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Getting following error while run docker build...

```
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Comment: What was the command?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because the container i'm trying to access doesn't have the /bin/bash executable.

Replace `RUN ["/bin/bash"...` by `RUN ["/bin/sh"...`

Answer (score 20):

Your container doesn't have `bash` installed but probably it has `sh` so run the container with (replace `/bin/bash` with `/bin/sh`):

```
docker exec -it username/imagename /bin/sh
```